# how to localise firebase notifications on Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am pretty new to this and I could not find much information online.

Android app receives a notification from the backend using `AndroidNotification.builder()` and we want to show messages in different languages on the app.

on the backend I have code to add `setBodyLocalizationKey` `setTitleLocalizationKey` so I Android can show in their localised language.

```
val androidNotifBuilder = AndroidNotification.builder()

        lockscreenNotificationFallback.let {
            androidNotifBuilder.setTitle(it.title.generateFallbackString())
            androidNotifBuilder.setBody(it.body.generateFallbackString())
            androidNotifBuilder.setTitleLocalizationKey(it.title.localLanguageKey.name)
            androidNotifBuilder.addAllTitleLocalizationArgs(it.title.retrieveParams())
            androidNotifBuilder.setBodyLocalizationKey(it.body.localLanguageKey.name)
            androidNotifBuilder.addAllBodyLocalizationArgs(it.body.retrieveParams())
        }

        androidNotifBuilder.build()
```

on Android side for instance if the key for `setBodyLocalizationKey` is `START_CH11` I have added localised strings in different languages.

for english i have set bellow string and so on for other languages

```
 <string name="START_CH11">this is START_CH11</string>
```

But when a notification comes in I do not see the messages which are set in the strings file.

apart from adding strings to different files is there anything else I need to do on Android side so the notifications can be localised please

what I found online was

```
public AndroidNotification.Builder setBodyLocalizationKey (String bodyLocKey)
Sets the key of the body string in the app's string resources to use to localise the body text.
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidNotification.Builder#setBodyLocalizationKey(java.lang.String)

What am I missing on Android side please, any info would be very helpful

Thanks in advance
R